# Protection against spurious wake in conditional_variable

Tags: c++, condition-variable

I am using condition_variable in this manner but I want to know if a loop is required to protect against spurious  wake or a predicate is sufficient to protect.

```
unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu_);  //OPTION1
cv_.wait(lock)
// dosomething
```

Whether such protection is required?

```
while( !check_predicate() )    //OPTION2
{
  cv_.wait(lock)
}
// dosomething
```

Or if this predicate is sufficient to protect

```
 cv_.wait(lock,[](){ return check_predicate(); };  //OPTION3
```

Comment: The `wait` overload taking a predicate implements exactly the loop you show in `OPTION2`. In other words, `OPTION3` is simply a convenient shortcut for `OPTION2`; the two behave identically.

Comment: In option 2 the loop provides extract protection,  but whether same protection is available in option3,if a spurious wake occurs?

Comment: Which part of "this overload of `wait` runs the exact same loop" do you find unclear?